# R Shiny: "variable lengths differ" error for boolean values, checkboxInput()

Tags: r, checkbox, output, shiny, rpart

I am trying to create a Shiny App that builds a Tree Plot using rpart().  I am using 12 predictors, and I want to designate use of each predictor through a checkboxInput() values.  I know that the values of each checkboxInput is boolean.  Normally, rpart() works when I multiply TRUE or FALSE by one of my predictors to designate use of that predictor.  I keep getting the following error:

Error in model.frame.default(formula = outcome ~ (input$Pred1 * meanrecchrge) +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'input$Pred1')

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
require(rpart)
require(rpart.plot)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Tree Diagram of Churn Data"),

sidebarLayout(    

 sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("MinSplitVal",
                  "Minsplit Value",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 40000,
                  value = 1)),

 mainPanel(
   plotOutput("TreePlot"))),

wellPanel(      
        h3("Predictors"),
checkboxInput("Pred1", "Mean total recurring charge", TRUE),
checkboxInput("Pred2", "% change in minutes of use", TRUE),
checkboxInput("Pred3", "% change in revenues", FALSE),
checkboxInput("Pred4", "Months in service", FALSE),
checkboxInput("Pred5", "Number of unique substitutes",  FALSE),
checkboxInput("Pred6", "Number of active substitutes", FALSE),
checkboxInput("Pred7", "Days owning current equipment", FALSE),
checkboxInput("Pred8", "Age of first HH member", FALSE),
checkboxInput("Pred9", "Low credit rating -de", FALSE),
checkboxInput("Pred10", "Refurbished handset", FALSE),
checkboxInput("Pred11", "Web-capable handset", FALSE),
checkboxInput("Pred12", "Customer called retention team", FALSE)
)

))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
require(rpart)
require(rpart.plot)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {


output$TreePlot <- renderPlot({rpart.plot({rpart(outcome~
                  (input$Pred1*meanrecchrge)+(input$Pred2*percchangemin)
                 +(input$Pred3*percchangerev)+(input$Pred4*servmonths)
                 +(input$Pred5*numuniqsubs)+(input$Pred6*numactvsubs)
                 +(input$Pred7*daysowned)+(input$Pred8*agefirst)
                 +(input$Pred9*creditde)+(input$Pred10*refurb)
                 +(input$Pred11*webcap)+(input$Pred12*retcall), 
                 data = ChurntrainPreImpute, method = "class", 
                control = rpart.control(minsplit = 1))})
})
 })
```

Comment: To anyone reading this question, I ended up reprogramming the App.  Instead of using each input$Pred# value, I gave each predictor a text designation:

    text1 <- reactive({
      if(input$Pred1) paste("meanrecchrge")
    })

I compiled these into an overall text and used the as.formula() function to use the selected predictors in rpart.  Still, if anyone knows the answer to my original question, that would be awesome for future reference.  This way is probably cleaner code-readability wise.